# Javascript hash/convert function name

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I have part of code like this:

```
var test = new startClear.Cleaner('key', {floor: 100});
```

My point is, how to convert **startClear** function to something like this:
**5azjfxa123**. (or other)
This same with **floor**  ex. **ooas**
and then use: azjfxa.Cleaner('key', {ooas21: 100});

Is any possible to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Variable name cannot starts with a number.

Comment: What you are trying to do is a form of *Obfuscation* (so you can search for the correct term)

Comment: if you want to obfuscate your code, you can use for example : https://javascriptobfuscator.herokuapp.com/

Comment: olikaf thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tool like https://javascriptobfuscator.herokuapp.com/ .

make sure to enable "rename globals" (as your function names can be global names, especially).

Example :

(with only "Rename globals" enabled, and "hexadecimal" for *Identifier Names Generator* option)

```
// Paste your JavaScript code here
function abcdefgh() {
  console.log("Hello World!");
}
abcdefgh();
```

has become :

```
function _0x3120f9() {
    console['log']('Hello\x20World!');
}
_0x3120f9();
```

It is an open source library / tool. See here for the code : https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator

Comment: var c = b('0x0');
var d = new startClear.Cleaner[(b('0x1'))](c, { 'floor': 0.5 });
if (!d[b('0x2')]() && !d[b('0x3')](0x3840)) {
    d[b('0x4')]();
}
look it doesn't change startClear ;(

Comment: But where is your `startClear` function defined ? The tool cannot rename it if it doesn't have the definition

Comment: @Jensej You need to give the definition of startClear. If the obfuscator would change names without changing also how they were defined, then the code wouldn't work anymore : this is valid  `function myFunction() { console.log('hello)}; myFunction();` -> this is not valid anymore  `function myFunction() {console.log('hello') }; sdvaeg3r51();`